# How to get 95% CI for each level of a random effect in a lmer mixed model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval, random-effects

I have run several mixed models in `lme4` with some main effects, a few interaction terms, and two random effects (`animalID` and `year`). My model looks like this:

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ ns(area_scale, df = 3) + 
   area_scale:spat_scale + area_scale:temp_scale + 
   NDVI_scale:spat_scale + NDVI_scale:temp_scale + 
   spat_scale*temp_scale + NDVI_scale + (1|animal) + (1|year), 
   data = data, REML=TRUE)
```

I am trying to find a way to determine confidence intervals for each level of my animal and year random effects for the purposes of creating an effects plot to depict how these effects change over years and differ between animals.

When I run `ranef(model)`, I am able to find the mean effect value for each level of the random effects, and I have been able to find the overall standard deviation and variance for the entire random effect using `VarCorr(model)`.

I have seen ways to extract CIs for each level of a RE in an lme model, but am not finding any way to extract them for lmer models.

Any help?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. You already have an answer for your question. Please keep in mind that SO is focuseed on coding related questions. Your questions seems more statistics orientated. For statistical questions Cross Validated is the place to be: https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that the intervals you get are *not* technically confidence intervals (i.e., random effects values are not 'parameters', you can't use the CIs to test hypotheses about the group-level values), there are several built-in tools:

```
library(lme4)
example(lmer)
rr <- ranef(fm1)
class(rr) ## ranef.mer
methods(class = "ranef.mer")
## [1] as.data.frame plot          print
```

`as.data.frame` gives you the standard deviations of the conditional modes, which you can use however you want (e.g. compute `condval ± 1.96*condsd`):

```r
head(as.data.frame(rr), 3)
##    grpvar        term grp    condval   condsd
## 1 Subject (Intercept) 308   2.258551 12.07086
## 2 Subject (Intercept) 309 -40.398738 12.07086
## 3 Subject (Intercept) 310 -38.960409 12.07086
```

This gives you a built-in effects plot:

```
lattice::dotplot(rr)
```

(`lattice` is a built-in R package, you don't need to install it separately)

[image]

You can also get random effects values and confidence intervals with the `broom.mixed` package:

```r
broom.mixed::tidy(fm1, effects = "ran_vals", conf.int = TRUE)
```

You can also get effects plot for the random effects terms, and information about the conditional standard deviations, from the `ggeffects` package and/or the `sjPlot` package ...

These plots are also often called 'caterpillar plots', so [searching SO with this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+lme4+caterpillar+plot) will get you more information ...

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely answered my question :)